# VertexAI code-bison generates Python within markdown instead of Python

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

VertexAI code-bison sometimes generates Python code within markdown even though I explicitly asked for Python. OpenAI GPT3.5 never does that. Any ideas what to do so code-bison doesn't generate markdown?

Example prompt:

```
I'm going to give you a python function to validate data and I want you to help me modify it. Keep your answer short. No need to explain what you are doing.

The function takes row as an input. row is a dictionary with the following keys:

'size', 'product_type'

The function returns True when row is valid and False when row is invalid.

Define values globally. Don't put the values inside the function. Include the global variables in the function parameters definition.
Don't rename the existing variable names.

Description of when row is valid:

###
When product type is shoes, size can be from 8, 9, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, to 12.
###

Python function:

###
valid_values1 = []

def check(row, valid_values1):
    return row['size'] in valid_values1
```

code-bison result:

````
```python
valid_values1 = [8, 9, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12]

def check(row, valid_values1):
    return row['size'] in valid_values1 and row['product_type'] == 'shoes'
```
````

Comment: You can switch from the default view to the formatted(markdown) view by clicking the [markdown](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/learn/streaming#genai-studio) button. If this does not satisfy your requirement, can you provide the expected output and a little bit more details about your requirements?

Comment: I'm using the Vertexai Python SDK. I did not specify anywhere in the Python client that I wanted the answer in Markdown. The response to some prompts comes as Markdown, and to others, it comes as Python.

Comment: I got the desired output when I specified in the input that the result should not include comments or markdown. Additionally, you could try using pre-processing methods to eliminate markdown from the result. Please inform me if you would like me to share my discoveries as an answer.

Comment: Hi @Seperman,I have posted an answer to give a better idea. I hope it will help you. Do consider upvoting and accepting if it helps, otherwise let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following way to avoid comment:

- In your input string, specify that the output should not contain any markdown , comments, etc.
- Pre-processing the output: You can preprocess the output  by removing comments and markdown using some pre-processing technique.

**Example:**

```
import re
import time
import os

requirements="note that I want output without any comment or markdown"

def  vetexaicode(inputstring:str):
    prefixs=inputstring + requirements
    vertexai.init(project="my-project", location="us-central1")
    parameters = {
    "max_output_tokens": 1024,
    "temperature": 0.2,

    }
    model = CodeGenerationModel.from_pretrained("code-bison@001")
    response = model.predict(
    prefix = prefixs,
    **parameters
    )
    print(f"Response from Model: {response.text}")
    
    with open('a.txt','w') as filewrite:
        filewrite.write(response.text)  
    #time.sleep(4)    
    with open("a.txt",'r') as nefile:
        for line in nefile.readlines():
            if not re.match('^\#.*\#', line):       
                print(line)
    os.remove('a.txt')
```

**Note**: In the above example I am using a simple preprocessing technique(writing input to file and removing comments using regular expression) just to show a workaround .This may not work in the production environment.

Comment: Hi @kiran-mathew, Thanks for the response. Your response works because of your post processing and removing Markdown syntax. Overall, I was not satisfied with code-bison at all. Even the free version of OpenAI was better than code-bison. So I have not given it another shot. Thank though.